# Break a lua script in c++ from another thread?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, lua

I'm currently wrapping a lua class in c++ and it's going pretty well so far. But I'm wondering if there some way to break a lua script from running(could be in the middle of the script) for another thread. So if I run my lua script on thread 1, can I break it from thread 2? Would `lua_close(...)` do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Lua is not thread-safe so you'll have to be very careful not to screw stuff up

Comment: @SethCarnegie That's wrong. Lua is completely threadsafe (see [this message](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-07/msg00072.html) on lua-l).

Comment: @jpjacobs I mean that multiple threads using a single state is not safe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is an expected occurrence and most of the Lua script's time is spent inside Lua functions (i.e., not lengthy, blocking C calls), you could install a debug hook that checks for your "break flag" every N instructions and aborts the script. See the "debug library" section of [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/23.html).

Comment: That's a way to do it. But what if I don't use any bound C functions in a big loop or maby even an infinite loop. Then there must be some way to force the script to halt?

Comment: My point is that you can call assert(simpleCfunctionThatChecksFlagState()) from within the debug hook, thus throwing an error pretty quickly if Lua is in an infinite loop or otherwise executing. This approach doesn't work if you're blocked inside a long-running C function such as a synchronous I/O call.

Answer (score 2):

> Then there must be some way to force the script to halt?

No, there doesn't.

Lua provides exactly *one* thread safety guarantee: two separate `lua_State`s (separate being defined as different objects returned by `lua_open`) can be called freely from two different CPU threads. Thread A can call `lua_State` X, and thread B can call `lua_State` Y.

That is the **only** guarantee Lua gives you. Lua is inherently single-threaded; it only provides this guarantee because all of the global information for Lua is contained in a self-contained object: `lua_State`.

The rules of Lua require that only one thread talk to a `lua_State` at any one time. Therefore, it is impossible for Lua code to be executing and then be halted or paused by external C++ code. That would require breaking the rule: some other thread would have to call functions on this thread's `lua_State`.

If you want to abort a script in-progress, you will have to use debug hooks. This will dramatically slow down the performance of your script (if that matters to you). You will also need thread synchronization primitives, so that thread B can set a flag that thread A will read and halt on.

As for how you "abort" the script, that... is impossible in the most general case. And here's why.

The `lua_State` represents a Lua thread of execution. It's got a stack, a pointer to instructions to interpret, and some code it's currently executing. To "abort" this is not a concept that Lua has. What Lua does have is the concept of *erroring*. Calling `lua_error` from within C code being called by Lua will cause it to `longjmp` out of that function. This will also unwind the Lua thread, and it will return an error to the most recent function that handles errors.

Note: if you use `lua_error` in C++ code, you need to either have compiled Lua as C++ (thus causing errors to work via exception handling rather than `setjmp`/`longjmp`) or you need to make sure that *every* object with a destructor is off the stack when you call it. Calling `longjmp` in C++ code is not advisable without great care.

So if you issue `lua_pcall` to call some script, and in your debug hook, you issue `lua_error`, then you will get an error back in your `lua_pcall` statement. Lua's stack will be unwound, objects destroyed, etc. That's good.

The reason why this does not work in the *general* case (besides the fact that I have no idea how Lua would react to a debug hook calling `lua_error`) is quite simple: *Lua scripts* can execute `pcall` too. The error will go to the nearest `pcall` statement, whether it's in Lua or in C.

This Lua script will confound this method:

```
local function dostuff()
  while true do end
end

while true do
  pcall(dostuff)
end
```

So issuing `lua_error` does not guarantee that you'll "abort the script." Think of it like throwing exceptions; *anyone* could catch them, so you can't ensure that they are only caught in one place.

In general, you should never *want* to abort a Lua scripts execution in progress. This is not something you should be wanting to do.

Comment: Thank you. But what do you think about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862256/how-can-i-end-a-lua-thread-cleanly

Comment: @user1188404: That describes exactly what I said about using a debug hook. And it fails in exactly the way I describe; an error does not guarantee that the script ends.