# What does LUA acronym stand for?

Tags: lua

Many people write **LUA** when referring to the programming language developed since 1993 at the *Pontifical Catholic University of Rio de Janeiro* (PUC-Rio).

So what does that acronym stand for?

Comment: It is info you can find _on their site_: http://www.lua.org/about.html#name

Comment: "Many people write LUA when referring to the programming language"  Those people are wrong.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The programming language is named **Lua**, it is officially **not** a acronym.

*Lua* is a common word meaning *Moon* in Portuguese. The language is named like this because a previous programming language at PUC (in early development phase) was already named *SOL* for *Simple Object Language*. And since *SOL* means *Sun* in Portuguese, its successor has been named *Lua* as a joke.

An interesting backronym has been invented by the Lua community to ironically explain that Lua is not an acronym: LUA would stand for *Lua Uppercase Accident*.

Historically however, LUA *used* to be an acronym in Portuguese. It once meant *Linguagem para Usuarios de Aplicação* (Language for Application Users). The acronym was however never used in English documentation, because it would have been hard for non-Portuguese speakers to understand it.

---

On an other hand, Microsoft unfortunately uses LUA acronym to refer to the *Least privileged User Account*. This concept has nothing to do with the programming language, but contributes to a certain confusion.

Comment: That bit about *LUA* being an acronym in Portuguese was really mostly a joke. But it does appear in the source code of Lua 1.0.

Comment: I am brazillian yay! I tried to find that info for you Max E, but I failed.

But I can tell you that SOL (and another language that now I forgot the name) were a pair of configurations tools made for Petrobras, that hired PUC-Rio to do it.

Maybe knowing that you can find something...

PUC means "Pontifícia Universidade Católica"

Comment: @MaxE. Yes, SOL and DEL (Data Entry Language) were developed individually for PETROBRAS. From what I have read, they have never been released to that company; instead Lua, merging the concept of both languages, has been finally delivered to PETROBRAS, with success.

Comment: Anyone at PUC who can dig those out of the archives, I'll be your best friend forever.

Comment: The relation of SOL and DEL to Lua is documented in the HOPL paper [The Evolution of Lua](http://www.lua.org/doc/hopl.pdf).

Comment: That Lua Uppercase Accident is also in `/usr/share/misc/acronyms.comp`. I came here looking for more context but I guess it's just as expected - a silly joke. It's fun.