# Changing simple int into an object that can be passed by a reference into a Lua scripter

Tags: c#, lua, runtime

I'm working on a program that controls character in a game.
I want my users to be able to write Lua scripts in my program for the game.

There's an `int` variable in my program, `int SelfManaPc`, that is passed into scripter in that way: `lua_compiler["SelfManaPc"] = SelfManaPc;`.

This variable is being changed pretty fast in my main program in a different thread.
My problem is, that it is passing value only into Lua scripter, not the pointer.
After value change in C# program, in Lua scripts it doesn't change anymore.

I've made my solution and it works pretty well (`SelfManaPc` is now an object of my own class `Integer` so I can pass the pointer instead of value).

C# class:

```
  public class Integer
    {
        int value;
        public Integer(int xd) { value = xd; }

        public void Set(int xd) {value = xd;}
        public int Get() { return value; }        
    }
```

Example of use in Lua code:

```
while true do
    Say(SelfManaPc:Get())
    Sleep(2000);
end
```

If there's no other way, I'll leave it like that. But, I wanted to ask any of you first about any other ideas. It's kinda stupid to access `int` with `Get` and `Set` so some of you might know some nice trick.

Comment: First, please have a look to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615975

Comment: Did you try passing it with the ref keyword to pass it by reference and not by value? I'm just not sure if that's feasible in your scenario

Answer (score 1):

If there are several such variables in your script, you can consider placing them inside a single global table, for example named `options`. Then you add a *metatable* to that table: `__index` metamethod returns the value of a variable given its name, and `__newindex` metamethod sets a new value to a variable given its name.

How to implement this depends on the binding library you are using for C#.

Example of use in Lua code:

```lua
while true do
    Say(options.SelfManaPc)
    Sleep(2000)
    options.SelfManaPc = 1000 -- sets new value
    Sleep(500)
end
```