# "memory allocation error: block too big" doing simple integer division

Tags: lua, stm32

I have a weird issue.  LUA 5.3.5, compiled on STM32F429.  Free RAM is about 1Mb (memory allocation is using external SDRAM, not the more limited internal RAM on the STM32).  Note that working with things like strings works fine, as well.  It only seems to be division causing the problem.

This script works:

```
a=100
b=20
c=a+b
print(c)
```

This script returns "memory allocation error: block too big:"

```
a=100
b=20
c=a/b
print(c)
```

Further research is showing that the problem is not with the division, at all.  It is with tostring() which is called by print().  For some reason, tostring() is trying to allocate too much memory when dealing with the result from direct division.

In lstring.c, is the following:

```
   luaS_newlstr(): 
   if (l >= (MAX_SIZE - sizeof(TString))/sizeof(char))
      luaM_toobig(L);
```

When the issue occurs, l == 0xd0600f56
(interestingly, that is a memory address location in the range of the external SDRAM, rather than a valid string size).

If I modify the LUA script to do the following, it works fine:

```
a=100
b=20
c=math.floor(a/b)
print(c)
```

I checked and in both cases, c is type==number

As for the question regarding the memory allocation, we are using the dlmalloc() library, configured like this during LUA startup:

```
  ezCmdLua = lua_newstate(ezlua_poolalloc, NULL);
  int error = luaL_loadbuffer(ezCmdLua, bfr, len, "ezCmdLua");
  if (!error)
  {
    error = lua_pcall(ezCmdLua, 0, 0, 0);
    if (error) {
...
    }
  }

....

static void *ezlua_poolalloc (void *ud, void *ptr, size_t osize, size_t nsize) {
  (void)ud; (void)osize;  /* not used */
  if (nsize == 0) {
    dlfree(ptr);
    return NULL;
  }
  else
    return dlrealloc(ptr, nsize);
}
```

I have confirmed that memory allocation is working properly, and I can do things like string manipulation and printing of strings with no problem at all.  In fact, when debugging this issue, the luaS_newlstr() function is called several times prior to the issue occurring, and each time l (the length of the string) is a reasonable value.  That is, until I try to print the result of the division.  Moving the division around in the script makes no difference (ie, adding things before it like other print statements), so I doubt the stack is being trashed.

Comment: This is quite an interesting problem, but to diagnose it, you'd need to provide more details. If you're using an external RAM, you probably pointed the C memory manager, and thus Lua, to use it? Perhaps the division is somehow using a different allocation method?

Comment: Additional details added.

Comment: Further research:  I reverted back to using the standard memory allocation calls (using luaL_newstate()) and it made no difference, so using dlmalloc() is not a cause of the problem.  Still crashed in tostring().  More testing: replacing print(c) with print("%d", c) works fine.  print("%f", c) hard faults if compiler optimizations are turned on, or prints nothing at all (and throws no errors) if optimizations are off.  The fact that optimizations are affecting the outcome makes me concerned with how stable LUA is on STM32/ARM/gcc.

Comment: This might well be a bug. I'm not a Lua maintainer, but it sounds interesting to try and pin down. Unfortunately I'm going to be away from the keyboard for the next two weeks... Diagnosing this would probably require debugging Lua itself, but that's actually less daunting/scary than it sounds, the sources are pretty straightforward to follow. If you can attach gdb to your board you could do that in-situ, and regardless might be a good idea to try reproducing that on e.g. ARM QEMU first - if it happens there, you have a ready bug report.

Comment: Perhaps this is a little off-topic as comment, however I would like to mention that the correct name for the language is "Lua" and not "LUA". It's the Portuguese word for moon and officially not an acronym. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615975/what-does-lua-acronym-stand-for)

Comment: Lua5.4 added `unlikely` to that line, perhaps to fix that error?  https://www.lua.org/source/5.4/lstring.c.html  as opposed to https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lstring.c.html  Do you have the ability to compile with 5.4 on that device, and if so, does it have any effect?