# Problem reading back value from table in Lua

Tags: c++, pointers, lua

I've "inherited" an application that uses Lua with c++.

To move data between the two, the data is pushed to a table and read back.
At some point a pointer-value to some data is also stored this way. But apparently the value that is read back is always zero.
I don't know much about Lua, so could someone please explain why this suddenly fails (it has been working, but something has changed)

Lua version is 5.2.1 (I've made sure it's the same version in both working/non-working environment)

Data is pushed like this:

`lua_pushstring(L, "data"); lua_pushinteger(L, (u32)pData->pucImageData); lua_settable(L, -3);`

I get this in the log

> PUSHEntry (key=data, v=-1451470840)

and popped like this

```
u32 uValue = 0;
lua_pushstring(L, key);
lua_gettable(L, iTableIndex);  /* get table[key] */
uValue = (u32)lua_tonumber(L, -1); // Retrieve value
printf("ReadEntry (key=%s, v=%d) \n", key, uValue);
lua_pop(L, 1);  /* remove number from stack */
```

where I only get this back

> ReadEntry (key=data, v=0)

Comment: Did you try printing the value in Lua? Also, this code will break on 64-bit platforms.

Comment: See my old question https://stackoverflow.com/q/13615975

Comment: How do you get a negative integer in the log when you're explicitly casting to `u32`? Something isn't adding up here. Provide more code. What even is this `pData->pucImageData`?

Comment: Normally, to store pointers in Lua, you should use *light userdata* values. Those are opaque to Lua.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

The problem turned out to be that the big number was pushed with `lua_pushinteger`. Changing this to `lua_pushnumber` fixed the issue.

I agree that this needs some cleaning up for 64-bit platforms.